# How to get object of relationship in Neo4jClient?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

In this query will return multi type of relationship

```
var e = GraphClientClass.GetInstance().Client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person)-[rel]-(other:Person)")
            .Return((person, rel, other) => new
            {
                person = person.As<Person>(),
                rel = rel.As<Metadata>(),
                other = other.As<Person>()
            }).Results;
```

in this case rel just return properties data.But i need to know type of each relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd put:

```
.Return((person, rel, other) => new 
{
    person = person.As<Person>(),
    rel = rel.As<Metadata>(),
    relType = Return.As<string>("type(rel)"),
    other = other.As<Person>()
})
```

`relType` would be the type of the relationship in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to return `type(rel)` in the return statement.